# i want to get same dov repeatedly when a button is clicked in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I have an input box and a button. When I click on that button the text in the above input box will be printed on another div. But when i typed another text and pressed the button again, the new message comes on the same div and previous text is become erased. I want the new text comes below from the previous div. like chat box..please help me.

Comment: Please add your code and tell us, what you've done so far. We're not doing your whole work.

Comment: Show what of you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

```
`function add_text (){var input = $('input.foo').text();$('body').append('<p>'+ input + '<p>')}`
```

call this function on click of submit button